# Multiline string substitution on bash stream

Tags: bash, perl, sed, grep

I have a large (>500GB) Postgres dump in GCS that I would like to strip `COPY` commands from. Given the size of the dump I would like to perform the substitution on a `gsutil cat` stream rather than storing locally:

```sh
gsutil cat gs://mybucket.mydomain.com/path/to/mydump.sql | some_command > mydump-commands.sql
```

The `COPY` command can span multiple lines but always ends with `\.` on its own line.

I have tried with perl:

```sh
# some_command = 
perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/COPY.*\\.//smg'
```

this works for a small sample local file (below) but does not seem to work streaming from stdin.

```sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: mytable; Type: TABLE; Schema: dummy; Owner: bchrobot
--

CREATE TABLE dummy.mytable (
    id integer,
    title text
);


ALTER TABLE dummy.mytable OWNER TO bchrobot;

--
-- Data for Name: mytable; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: dummy; Owner: bchrobot
--

COPY dummy.mytable (id, title) FROM stdin;
1   my first title
2   my second title
\.


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Any suggestions for this, specifically for working with streams?

Comment: You need to escape the period as well `\\\.`.

Comment: If you are trying to slurp the input with `undef $/`, that's going to soak up 500Gb of memory, is it not? Do you have limitations on your storage space? What size do you expect the output to be?

Comment: _does not **seem** to work_ : It is unclear what this means. You did not show how exactly you invoked the command, when the input is not a file, but stdin, and you also did not explain in what respect it did not work. The **seem** sounds weird to me: Either it works or it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `sed` command, as the replacement of `some_command`, will delete all lines between a line beginning with `COPY` and a line consisting of `\.`, including those two lines.

```
sed '/^COPY/,/^\\\.$/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to escape the period as well `\.`. And since you have some beginning `^` and end of line `$` restrictions, you should add those as well.

Since you are streaming the input, you can't `undef $/` or it will try to read all 500Gb into memory, and your program will probably just hang. You have to read in line-by-line mode.

You might try a [flip-flop operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators):

```
perl -ne'print unless /^COPY/ ... /^\\\.$/' psql.txt
```

The range operator `...` (or `..`) will be true if the LHS pattern match is true, and for every line after, until and including when the RHS pattern is true. And false otherwise.

So we print all the lines that are not included in this passage.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pg_dump` with the `--schema-only` option,

> `--schema-only` Dump only the object definitions (schema), not data. This option is the inverse of --data-only. It is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying `--section=pre-data --section=post-data`.

Comment: The dump is an archive I inherited from a database that no longer exists so unfortunately pg_dump is not an option